# Error: "channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed" on OS X Screen Sharing over ssh tunnel

Tags: macos, vnc, ssh-tunnel, screensharing

I had configured OS X screen sharing over an ssh tunnel and at some point it stopped working. The ssh tunnel would work:

```
ssh -L 1202:localhost:5900 user@remote-host.com
```

However, when attempting to make the screen sharing connection (`vnc://localhost:1202`), the remote host would error with

```
channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the following in my remote host's `~/.ssh.config`:

```
AllowTCPForwarding yes
PermitOpen any
```

The missing element was an entry in the remote host's `/etc/hosts` that defined `localhost`. I added the following to that file and screen sharing over ssh tunnel was restored:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Check also the conf files located in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf`, these files  are  included at the start of the configuration file, so options  set  there  will  override  those  in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.